# merge two json objects in to one object by id

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have two json objects like this:

```
Object 1:

{
   "jcat":[
      {
         "TITLE":"SEO",
         "ID":"27",
      },
      {
         "TITLE":"Functions and Events",
         "ID":"2"
      },
]
}

Object 2:

{
  "job":[
  {
     "PCATID":"27",
     "CC":"AHE",
     "JNUM":"01488"
  },
  {
     "PCATID":"27",
     "CC":"EBS",
     "JNUM":"01489"
  },
]}
```

they have common ids(ID and PCATID) but they are named different.

How can i merge them so that final objects looks like:

Object 3:

```
{
   "jcat":[
      {
         "TITLE":"SEO",
         "ID":"27",
         "CC":"AHE",
         "JNUM":"01488"
      },
      {
         "TITLE":"SEO",
         "ID":"27",
         "CC":"EBS",
         "JNUM":"01489"
      },

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real easy way to do this.  But the following will work:

```
var obj1 = {
   "jcat":[
      {
         "TITLE":"SEO",
         "ID":"27",
      },
      {
         "TITLE":"Functions and Events",
         "ID":"2"
      }]
};

var obj2 = 
{
  "job":[
  {
     "PCATID":"27",
     "CC":"AHE",
     "JNUM":"01488"
  },
  {
     "PCATID":"27",
     "CC":"EBS",
     "JNUM":"01489"
  }
]};

var newObj = {jcat:[]};
newObj.jcat[0] = $.extend(true, {}, obj1.jcat[0], $.map([obj2.job[0]],function(e){
    return {CC:e.CC, JNUM:e.JNUM};
})[0]);
newObj.jcat[1] = $.extend(true, {}, obj1.jcat[0], $.map([obj2.job[1]], function(e){
    return {CC:e.CC, JNUM:e.JNUM};
})[0]);
```

**JS FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/XmsX4/1/